# what's percentmemoryn in hive?

Tags: hive

Hive version:3.0.0

when I type  `$HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver2`

I got:

```
WARN  [main] conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.map.aggr.hash.percentmemoryn does not exist
```

**Problem:**
What's `percentmemoryn` and where can I find the relevant document ?

here's [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtyOa.jpg)

Thanks for your help.